# A Part of my Component for my React Project App is not showing

Tags: reactjs, components, mapbox, render

Really frustrating hiccup.
I have a React app where there are one Mapbox map in each route, and the Map itself in one Component on one route is not being rendered. I have two routes( /dispatcher/map, and /medical ) in which is Wrapper.js, in which is the Map.js each:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import DispatcherWrapper from "./Dipatcher/Wrapper";
import DispatcherMapWrapper from "./DispatcherMap/Wrapper/Wrapper";
import MedicWrapper from "./Medic/Wrapper/Wrapper";
import Login from "./loginPage";

const App = () => {
  
  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Route path="/dispatcher" exact component={DispatcherWrapper} />

        <Route path="/dispatcher/map" exact component={DispatcherMapWrapper} />
        
        <Route path="/medical" exact component={MedicWrapper} />
        <Route path="/" exact component={Login} />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I have tested the maps out in another react app, and it works perfectly fine. It shows up. But when I have copied and pasted the Map.js into our real project folder, only the sidebar will show up which is below:

```
<div className="sidebar">
    Longitude: {lng} | Latitude: {lat} | Zoom: {zoom}
</div>
```

The actual map component of :

Will not show up in the React.

My suspicion is, because the very sam Map.js file was working beautifully on my other test react app, that file would not be the issue in this actual project app, since I copied and pasted the file. Nevertheless: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ba1Cu.png)

Looking for solutions in how to make the Map appear.

Comment: Can you post out the code for other components as well?

Comment: Please try to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example. Can you share the route components that are rendering a map, and the map component?